# Using C# .Net Core, how do I pass the contents of a textbox to a modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, modal-dialog

I am currently working on a view (in a C# .Net Core 2.1 web application) that is intended to have a "Search string" text box and an "Add Item" button that should open up a modal that will have a list of all items (from the database) that match the search string, with a "Select" button or link in order to add the item.

But I'm at a loss to figure out how to pass the text box results to the modal action.

Note: I know I have a work-around in that I could code it as a completely separate view/action (i.e. not a modal), probably adding logic to the existing form submit action, but it'd be nice if I could keep the modal idea.

Here is the code of what I tried so far (but to no avail):

Controller:

```
    public IActionResult AddItem(string SearchString)
    {
        var model = _context.BasicItems
            .Where(i => i.Name.Contains(SearchString));

        return PartialView("_AddKitItem", model);
    }
```

The in the view that I have the text box and button (which now I'm using a ViewModel rather than my original Model entity - note: the ViewModel is just an object containing the original entity I wanted to use - in this case called a Kit - and a string called SearchString):

```
<div id="modal-placeholder"></div>
```

(then some other controls)

```
            <label asp-for="SearchString" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="SearchString" class="form-control" />


            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-target="#add-item" data-url="@Url.Action("AddItem")">
                Search Item To Add
            </button>
```

I also have the following JS code (that I took from sample code)

```
$(function () {
    var placeholderElement = $('#modal-placeholder');

    $('button[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function (event) {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        $.get(url).done(function (data) {
            placeholderElement.html(data);
            placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
        });
    });

    placeholderElement.on('click', '[data-save="modal"]', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');

        var actionUrl = form.attr('action');

        var dataToSend = form.serialize();

        $.post(actionUrl, dataToSend).done(function (data) {

            var newBody = $('.modal-body', data);
            placeholderElement.find('.modal-body').replaceWith(newBody);

            var isValid = newBody.find('[name="IsValid"]').val() == 'True';
            if (isValid) {
                placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When that didn't work (by putting a breakpoint on the first line of the AddItem action in the controller and checking the SearchString value - which was null), on the main view I replaced the two SearchString controls with the following

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SearchString)
                    :
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SearchString)
```

But still no luck - same result.

So then I even tried:

```
Item Name:

                @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
```

And still the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Scott use

```
asp-for="@model.SearchString"
```